# Oracle Stored Procedure Call from iSQL PLUS Invalid Identifier

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, isql

I have created a procedure using the following code using iSQL Plus on Firefox. The procedure compiles successfully.

```
create or replace procedure get_staff  (
    product_no in varchar2,
    o_cursor out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
        open o_cursor for
        'select sr.name, sr.bonus from sales_staff sr inner join product p on p.sales_staff_id = sr.staff_id where product_no = ' || product_no ;
end;
```

I am trying to call this procedure using the following code

```
var rc refcursor
exec get_staff('A56',:rc)
print rc
```

I get the following error.

```
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00904: "A56": invalid identifier 
ORA-06512: at "AA2850.GET_STAFF", line 6 
ORA-06512: at line 1 
ERROR: 
ORA-24338: statement handle not executed 
SP2-0625: Error printing variable "rc"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the case you have, there's no need for dynamic sql:

```
open o_cursor for
        select sr.name, sr.bonus 
          from sales_staff sr 
               inner join product p 
                       on p.sales_staff_id = sr.staff_id
         where p.product_no = product_no;
```

if you were using dynamic SQL then ideally you would in most cases want to bind:

```
open o_cursor for
        'select sr.name, sr.bonus 
          from sales_staff sr 
               inner join product p 
                       on p.sales_staff_id = sr.staff_id
         where p.product_no = :b1' using product_no;
```

failing that (edge cases, sometimes you want to avoid bind variables for skewed data), varchar2s need enclosing in quotes:

```
open o_cursor for
        'select sr.name, sr.bonus 
          from sales_staff sr 
               inner join product p 
                       on p.sales_staff_id = sr.staff_id
         where p.product_no = ''' ||product_no||'''';
```

but you should escape single quotes and validate that product_no has no semi colons etc (i.e. careful of SQL injection)